# Comparing user input of Strings in Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, compare, user-input

I am having trouble creating a functional user input/ compare program of a string in Assembly. Here is part of my program below:

```
li $v0, 8
la $a0, userInput
syscall

la $t2, userInput
la $t3, y
la $t4, Yes

lb $t5, 0($t2)
lb $t6, 0($t3)
lb $t7, 0($t4)

beq $t5, $t6, main
beq $t5, $t7, main
```

The code above functions properly when comparing the user input to the 'Yes' existing String but it does not function properly when the user inputs a string matching the 'y' string. Each of these strings is only one character long. It seems as though that line of code is somehow skipped over. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your target CPU?

Comment: Some MIPS assemblers require you to fill the delay slot explicitly. Try adding a `noop` between the two `beq` instructions and/or consult your manual.

Comment: I'm using QTSPIM, the noop between the beq instructions did not work; thank you for trying. Any other ideas as to how to fix the problem?

Comment: Single step in QTSPIM and look at what's happening. Check values of registers.

Comment: I figured it out. It is because I only gave my string one bit of space thinking that it would be sufficient. I needed to give it 3. Thanks for the help!